# Powershell Command Giving Error On Execution

Tags: powershell

I am trying to forward Windows Security events from my forwarder server to a collector. So I performed some configurations and I'm able to get every other Windows event (i.e. System, Application, etc.) except Security events.

I'm getting the error below:

Error - Last retry time: 4/21/2020 7:20:07 AM. Code (0x138C): Windows Event Forward plugin can't read any event from the query since the query returns no active channel. Please check channels in the query and make sure they exist and you have access to them.  Next retry time: 4/21/2020 8:20:07 AM.

I checked around and found the articles below:

- https://rockyprogress.wordpress.com/2011/12/04/security-event-log-collection-from-a-domain-controller/
- https://community.microfocus.com/t5/ArcSight-User-Discussions/Error-0x138c-when-deploy-Windows-Event-Forwarding/td-p/1577930

In PS I ran the command:

```
wevtutil sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)
```

But I get the error:

```
At line:1 char:38
+ wevtutil sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;; ...
+                                      ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:52
+ wevtutil sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;; ...
+                                                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:55
+ wevtutil sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;; ...
+                                                       ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:65
+ ... util sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1; ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:68
+ ... il sl security /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;; ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:88
+ ... BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1; ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:91
+ ... G:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;; ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:107
+ ... ;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression
```

I see what it's complaining about but can't make sense as to why as it looks fine to me. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell is interpreting the semicolons as statement terminators.  To prevent it from doing that, put quotes around the entire `/ca:` parameter...

```bsh
wevtutil sl security '/ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)'
```

Depending on how that application parses parameters, you may also be able to quote just the parameter's value

```bsh
wevtutil sl security /ca:'O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0005;;;SY)(A;;0x5;;;BA)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)'
```

Comment: Oh man. Yep this is what running on fumes does. I needed a second pair of eyes and you helped. Thanks!